# struggling with strings and lists in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have the following code in python:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sock,'html.parser')
for string in soup.stripped_strings:
    string = string.encode('ascii','ignore')
    print string
```

This prints:

```
the
cat
has
nine
lives
```

This continues for about 47 different strings. How do I get these separate strings into one list? i.e. (the, cat, has, nine, lives)

If I use:

```
print list(itertools.chain(string))
```

It prints out:

```
['c', 'a', 't']
etc...
```

Same thing happens when I use join...

If this is a duplicate question please just post a link to find it, I searched all over and have not been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[s.encode('ascii','ignore') for s in soup.stripped_strings]
```

List comprehension is a concise way to apply an operation for every item on iterable and create a list out of the result:

```
>>> [x * x for x in range(5)]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider reading http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm for list comprehension.

> You can also add items to an existing sequence. The append method adds
>   a single item to the end of the list, the extend method adds items
>   from another list (or any sequence) to the end, and insert inserts an
>   item at a given index, and move the remaining items to the right.

```
L.append(item)
L.extend(sequence)
L.insert(index, item)
```

you can use a for loop, and add items to a list...

```
  out = []
  for object in L:
      out.append(function(object))
```